# Keyboard not getting dismissed even I'm trying to dismiss Android

Tags: android

I have a editText , and two buttons when I click cancel, i have the disable the edit text and hide keyboard.

```
     case R.id.verify_cancel:

 hideMobileNoEditOption();
            showAndHideError(verify_layout, false);
            showAndHideError(mobile_error_tv, false);
            mobile_number_et.clearFocus();
```

this is the code for hideMobileNoEditOption();

```
mobile_number_et.clearFocus();
        AppUtil.hideSoftKeyboard(this);
        mobile_number_et.setCursorVisible(false);
        mobile_number_et.setFocusable(false);
        mobile_number_et.setEnabled(false);
        mobile_number_et.setTextIsSelectable(false);
        mobile_number_et.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.zero_title));
```

and this is the code for hideing keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        if (null != activity.getCurrentFocus()) {

            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
```

But my key board is not getting dismissed for what reason God knows, can anyone please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you should ask god since he knows

Comment: Please help to find the solution.

Comment: Are you sure your `hideSoftInputFromWindow` method is executed? If you clear focus before hiding the soft keyboard  `(null != activity.getCurrentFocus())` condition returns false and wont hide your keyboard.

Comment: Thank you, it actually solved my problem, I was clearing the focus before i called hide keyboard. when i did the other way it solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this code is working for me

```
     /**
     * For Hiding the keyboard
     */

    public void hideKeyboard() {
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is like keyboard is hiding and coming back within a second.

Comment: are you using request focus or focus change listener ? Because it will open the keyboard

Comment: Ya, when I'm clearing the focus, edit text was gaining the focus again.